# spplot() lattice chart using row-wise data

Tags: r, graphics, rgdal

How can I create lattice chart using spplot() when data are arranged in rows, e.g. there are more values for every region (I have unemployment rate `unemp` for many years (`year`) for regions `CSO_NAME)`?

This is my code to load map and merge data:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sqldf)

# Import map and assign data.shape@data to spdata
data.shape<-readOGR(dsn="folder",layer="mylayer")    
spdata <- data.shape@data

# Load statistics data
unemp <- read.csv("cso_unemployment_rwise.csv")

# Merge data with spdata
spdata <- sqldf("select sp.*, cu.year, cu.unemp from spdata sp join unemp cu on (sp.nazok_a = cu.CSO_NAME) ")

# Build new spdata
spdata_merged <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(data.shape, spdata) 
# This fails: length(Sr@polygons) == nrow(data) is not TRUE
```

I thought I can use something similar as `formula`, e.g. like this example for barchart:

```
barchart(spdata$year~spdata$unemp|spdata$CSO_NAME)
```

But because I can't merge data with polygons I do not know what should be the next step. I can transpose data easily in this case and then use something like:

```
spplot(spdata,c("y2009","y2010","y2011","y2012",...))
```

**Reproducible Example**

Here are sample data, `stats_data` with only one grouping variable `year` and `stats_data2` with two grouping variables `year` and `sex`

```
# Get map
con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/CZE_adm2.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)
gadm_data <- gadm@data

# Create sample Data
stats_data <-
  data.frame(

      as.character(rep(gadm_data$NAME_2,3)),
      as.numeric(round(runif(3*length(gadm_data$NAME_2), 0, 1),digits=3)*100),
      as.factor(rep(c(2010,2011,2012),length(gadm_data$NAME_2)))
  )
names(stats_data) <- c("NAME_2","UNEMPR","YEAR") # str(stats_data)

# Add each year to map data
library("sqldf")
gadm_data <- sqldf("select gd.*, sd.UNEMPR as u2010 from gadm_data gd join stats_data sd using (NAME_2) where year = 2010")
gadm_data <- sqldf("select gd.*, sd.UNEMPR as u2011 from gadm_data gd join stats_data sd using (NAME_2) where year = 2011")
gadm_data <- sqldf("select gd.*, sd.UNEMPR as u2012 from gadm_data gd join stats_data sd using (NAME_2) where year = 2012")
gadm@data <- gadm_data

# Plot     
spplot(gadm,c("u2010","u2011","u2012"),at=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,70,100))

# Create sample Data, two factor variables
stats_data2 <-
  data.frame(

    as.character(rep(gadm_data$NAME_2,6)),
    as.numeric(round(runif(6*length(gadm_data$NAME_2), 0, 1),digits=3)*100),
    as.factor(rep(c(2010,2011,2012),2*length(gadm_data$NAME_2))),
    as.factor(c("f","m"))
  )
names(stats_data2) <- c("NAME_2","UNEMPR","YEAR","SEX") # str(stats_data2)
```

I can do the ugly data manipulation using `sqldf`, but this gets more and more complicated with more factors added. Suppose I have 2 factors with 2 and 10 values then I have to add 20 columns.

R version 2.15.1, Windows XP, SP3

Comment: You should have one row of data per polygon. It is hard to rewrite your code without a toy example. Always try to make questions [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381)

Comment: @SimonO101 I have added easily reproducible example to show how ugly code it is even for only one factor variable.

Comment: Great! I will have a look later when I get a chance to see if I can help you, and now you have a reproducible example I'm sure others will see if they can help too.